# Are there any ways to clean a mirror without water or cleaning spray?

Tags: glass

Are there any ways to clean a mirror without using water or any cleaning spray?

Comment: It might be worth explaining *why* you want to clean a mirror without water/spray in case that reveals any better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use a mechanical cleaning method**

You don't need any liquids at all.

If the mirror is made with float-glass which is quite flat and free from ripples, you can get excellent results with a razor blade at a sharp (heh) angle to mechanically 'scrape' the mirror clean. Use the same angle as you would to 'hone' the blade but push instead of pull the blade. This technique can cleanly remove finger prints and other surface dross. If you're careful, you can clean the mirror surface with a single blade before it gets too dull.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how dirty the mirror is. For loose dirt or dried-up soap spots, wiping with a soft cloth can be enough. If the mirror is coated with e.g. sand, you need to use water to prevent scratching the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lemon juice for cleaning mirrors. It is easy and usefull method for cleaning mirrors. Lemon are common thing in houses so you should use it .